# If I modify constraints, it doesn't look intuitive. in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

If I modify constraints in xcode, only the orange solid lines will be modified as shown in the picture. What is the reason?

[image]

Comment: If they’re in orange, that generally means that the constraints dictated that location, but that the view was dragged to some other location. You can tap the “update frames” button and it will move it back to where the constraints will place it at runtime. Then, when you want to have it placed in a different location, update the constraints rather than dragging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your constraints are showing as orange it means that they are not being respected. Moving your views doesn't update your constraints, so for example if your constraint says that the space between the leading margin and your button is 100, but you move it so it's 80, it will show up as orange.

In general you should avoid moving the views manually, always updating the constraints values instead. There's also a shortcut to set the frames of your views to the ones dictated by their constraints.